# Material switch icon overshadowed

Tags: android, xml, material-ui

In my android app, I am trying to add a switch, with a tick when enabled in its thumb. The tick's color should be white. The problem is, it is not visible through the blue. Playing around with the alpha messes with my colors, making it worse. Any help? That's kinda I am going for (Despite the tick here not being white):

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
            android:id="@+id/sw_inst_enabled"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.MaterialSwitch"
            android:scaleX="0.75"
            android:scaleY="0.75"
            android:checked="true"
            app:thumbIcon="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
            app:thumbTint="@color/switch_thumb_color"
            app:trackTint="@color/switch_track_color" />
```

---

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/white"
    android:pathData="M9,16.2L4.8,12l-1.4,1.4l5.6,5.6l12,-12L20.2,6.6z"/>
</vector>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

---